# SQLite ROUND showing error in Trigger Formulas

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLiteStudio under Debian x86

[image]

in the above fig as shown my `Trigger` for `Production` is evaluating to **zero** whereas it shouldn't
[image]

these are my data types

[image]

problem is resolved using `ROUND` with `Efficiency`

My question is that **Production is evaluated zero only for values having Efficiency as whole number** (no decimals) which is rectified via `ROUND` in the last fig. However ambiguity remains because Elements as well as Load (in some instances) are also whole numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide two integer values, the result is also an integer:

```
> SELECT 96 / 100;
0
```

This does not happen for any operation where a floating-point value is involved, but if the division was already calculated, it's too late:

```
> SELECT 1.0 * (96 / 100), (1.0 * 96) / 100;
0.0|0.96
```